# Trying to get a choice in a drop-down to be selected with Form.initial

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want a form to have a drop-down list of districts with one of them pre-selected according to some other data. To make one district be selected I would need to set *initial* to something like this:

```
class myExtendedContactInfoForm(ExtendedContactInfoForm):
    districts = [(x.id, x.district) for x in District.objects.all()]
    district = forms.ChoiceField(choices=districts, required=False, initial=2)
```

If I instantiate myExtendedContactInfoForm **without** setting *initial*, the drop-down works perfectly:

```
form = myExtendedContactInfoForm(contact=contact)
```

**However**, for the rest of the form to work, I actually need pass the *initial* data, so I must do this:

```
form = myExtendedContactInfoForm(contact=contact, initial=init_data)
```

But that makes the selection in the drop-down stop working. The reason is explained in the documentation. It says in the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial):

> Note that if a Field defines *initial* and you include *initial* when instantiating the Form, then the latter initial will have precedence.

How do I solve this problem? This is a bit like name-space pollution.

Many thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to overriding the form's `__init__` method, you could remove the `districts` key from the form's `init_data`. That way, the other fields are populated from the form's initial data, and the `districts` field uses its own initial value.

```
init_data.pop('districts', None)
form = myExtendedContactInfoForm(contact=contact, initial=init_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
class myExtendedContactInfoForm(ExtendedContactInfoForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'initial' in kwargs:
            kwargs['initial']['district'] = 2
        super(myExtendedContactInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do kwargs.update({'initial': {'district': 2}}) ? e.g. in case kwargs['initial'] is not set

Comment: @jpic No, `{'initial': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}.update({'initial': {'district': 2}}` will remove all existing initials.

Answer (score 1):

```
class myExtendedContactInfoForm(ExtendedContactInfoForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myExtendedContactInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['district'].initial = 2        

    districts = [(x.id, x.district) for x in District.objects.all()]
    district = forms.ChoiceField(choices=districts, required=False)
```

Comment: Why not use forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=District.objects.all()) ?

Comment: Won't work, form's initial [always has precedence](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L489) over field's.

Comment: Good point, I'll leave this here anyway - good to see why it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a different way of specifying the choices:

```
class MemberForm(forms.Form):
    google_account = forms.EmailField()
    group = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MemberForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['group'].choices = [(g.id,g.name) for g in get_group_choices()]
```

Where `get_group_choices()` does all the databse queries etc. Obviously you could do the queries in `__init__`, it's basically down to style at that point.

Using this method, I have never had a problem with initial values.

Edit: Somehow I completely misread the fact that you're trying to hard-code an initial value into the form. Could you just hard code the initial value into your view?

Comment: I'm not actually wanting to hard-code the value 2. I just wrote that for brevity. In reality it would be based on some other settings.

Comment: Either way, my preferred method of doing this would be to pass that value in to the initial in the views: `f = ContactForm(initial={'myfield':myvalue})`. Is there some reason why this doesn't work?